# I want to generate 2D octagon with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinates

I get a peculiar triangle with this code while I am trying to generate a regular octagon:

```
    var geom = new THREE.Geometry(); 

    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(100, 250, 0));
    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(250, 100, 0));
    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(250, -100, 0));
    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(100, -250, 0));
    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(-100, 250, 0));
    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(-250, -100, 0));
    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(-250, 100, 0));
    geom.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(-100, 250, 0));

    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3));
    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 4));
    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0, 4, 5));
    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0, 5, 6));
    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0, 6, 7));



    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, material);

    mesh.position.set(0, 0, -1000);

    scene.add(mesh);
```

Moreover one of the vertices of the generated triangle is placed somewhere I did not even mentioned in the code.
It is possible only the last added face is being shown, but I expect to see all the faces adjacent to each other forming a regular octagon.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why not to use [`THREE.CircleGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/CircleGeometry) or, at least, to have a look at its [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/CircleGeometry.js) to see how the things work? Order of vertices in a face has to be counter-clockwise. 5th and 8th points are equal, so you'll get something different from an octagon.

Comment: I wanted to transform these vertices later for animation, I am not sure If I can do that  THREE.CircleGeometry() .I apologize for such a stupid mistake which made you peruse such similar looking numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, order of vertices in a face is counter-clockwise, 5th and 8th points are different:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 500);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geom = new THREE.Geometry();

geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 250, 0));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(250, 100, 0));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(250, -100, 0));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, -250, 0));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-100, -250, 0)); //  y-coordinate is corrected
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-250, -100, 0));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-250, 100, 0));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-100, 250, 0));

geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 1)); // order of vertices
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 2));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 4, 3));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 5, 4));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 6, 5));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 7, 6));

geom.computeFaceNormals();
geom.computeVertexNormals();

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "white"
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);

scene.add(mesh);

var points = new THREE.Points(geom, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 20,
  color: 0xff0000
}));
scene.add(points); // just to visualize the points

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is anticlockwise criteria is completely new to me, I have seen tutorials which did not mention this, and it is not required when I a generate single face or triangle